# AngularJS - Get $scope variable from string

Tags: angularjs

So say I have a `$scope` variable defined like so:

```
$scope.data = {
    filter: {
        state: 'WA',
        country: 'US'
    }
};
```

How do I access that in a separate service by string? e.g. `data.filter` in the context of the `$scope`.

So say I have a service method like so:

```
function doSomething($scope, variableName) {
    // I want to access $scope[variableName] here??
}
```

I would call it from the controller like so:

```
service.doSomething($scope, 'data.filter');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will want use [$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval):

```
function doSomething($scope, variable) {
  var data = $scope.$eval(variable);

  // this logs {state: "WA", country: "US"}
  console.log(data);
}
```

However, if you wanted to do some functionality every time the contents changes, it would be preferable to use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

```
function doSomething($scope, variable) {
  $scope.$watch(variable, function(data) {
    // this logs {state: "WA", country: "US"}
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted to do an `angular.forEach` on the item, so I used `$eval` and it seems to work? And problems with that?

Comment: How forgetful of me for using $parse instead of $eval. Yes, eval works perfectly fine. If you look at the internal code, you'll see that $eval is just $parse, automatically using $scope as the context: `return $parse(expr)(this, locals);` I'll update with $eval.

Comment: Since services are singleton in angular, be very careful passing scope to services as the service may keep reference and scope may not get destroyed.

Comment: @Chandermani - So how do you pass objects from `$scope` into services to be `$watch`ed?

Comment: Services are source of information, and mostly $scopes are never passed to services. Data should be modified in service and other controllers should watch for these changes.

Comment: @Chandermani - Then how would one go about watching a collection in a service and notifying the controller when an item was changed? A small plunker would be great if you have any ideas. - Thanks!!

Comment: @Sam without knowing your exact use case, I would say reiterate what Chandermani said. The instead of passing information from the controller to the service, you would pass the information from the service to the controller. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecauz22p/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can access the variable with String via this snippet

```
var objAddress=variableName.split('.');
var yourVar=$scope.$eval(objAddress[0])[objAddress[1]];
```

Comment: This is answer, not question!